# Draw a point path using MotionLayout

Tags: android-motionlayout

Is there a way to draw in MotionLayout a view path without `canvas.drawPath(path, p)` ?

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS9qH.gif)

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufmjQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MotionLayout does not provide a drawing API.
There are many solutions to this.
The simplest no code solution is to Use Lottie
([Medium on Lottie animations in MotionLayout](https://mattiaferigutti.medium.com/controlling-lottie-animations-with-motion-layout-9f98fdccb45b))
Put a LottieAnimationView in the MotionLayout and drive the progress.

https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android?id=core-classes
The advantage is no code.
The disadvantage is it would not be dynamic to the shape of the phone/language

Building your own CustomView that is driven from MotionLayout is also very simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. This information will help quickly engage in the process.